# Which is faster "count" or "length"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming there are 2 models called `User` and `Post`

Which will be better performance(fast) either "Plan A" or "Plan B"?

"Plan A"

**controller**

```
@users = User.find_all_by_country(params[:country])
@posts = Post.find_all_by_category(params[:category])
```

**view**

```
<%= @users.count.to_s %>
<%= @posts.count.to_s %>
```

"Plan B"

**controller**

```
@users = User.find_all_by_country(params[:country])
@posts = Post.find_all_by_category(params[:category])
```

**view**

```
<%= @users.length.to_s %>
<%= @posts.length.to_s %>
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? Which one is faster?

Comment: Well. I probably have to research how to benchmark first

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In ruby, `count`, `length` and `size` all do pretty much the same thing regarding arrays. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550770/count-size-length-too-many-choices-in-ruby) for more info.

When using **ActiveRecord objects**, however, `count` is better than `length`, and `size` is even better.

`find_all_by_country` returns a dumb array so you shouldn't use that method (because it always returns an array). Instead, use `where(country: params[:country])`.

I'll let [Code School](http://www.codeschool.com/)'s [Rails Best Practices](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-best-practices) slide nº 93 speak for itself (and hope they don't get mad at me for reproducing it here).

[image]

Just in case the image gets taken down, basically:

1. `length` always pulls all the records and then calls .length on the array - bad
2. `count` always does a count query - good
3. `size` looks at the cache if you have a cache counter, otherwise does a count query - best

Comment: Thanks!!!. This is such perfect answer. Thanks very much:) In my application. I sometime delete records on phpMyAdmin. That's why it won't delete related records so that my counter cache will get messed up. That's the reason why I don't wanna use counter cache. In this situation, would you use just length instead?

Comment: @Foo Note that this answer is **wrong**, as you aren't invoking `length` or `count` on an ActiveResource relation, but on a plain old Ruby array. The length/count/size methods the slide is talking about aren't the same ones you're using.

Comment: @meagar In my understanding, once I fetch records by this `@users = User.find_all_by_country(params[:country])`, it won't invoke SQL query even if I do this in view. `<%= @users.length.to_s %>`

Comment: @Ashitaka That's even more wrong, `find_by` will return a single record which won't respond to `length` *or* `count`.

Comment: @Foo That is correct. Using the dynamic `find_all_by_` helpers produces a flat array of objects. Invoking length or count on it is different from invoking it on *any other array*, no SQL is involved. The point is that this isn't the best way to find the number of results, if that's all you need.

Comment: @Ashitaka Exactly as I pointed out in my answer, where you somewhat pompously told me "That's not how Rails works".

Comment: @meagar Thanks. Now I fully understood what you meant

Comment: Very clear answer. +1 for this ;) Thanks @Ashitaka very much.

Answer (score 1):

Both will be the same, `count` with no arguments and `length` are identical as you are invoking them on a Ruby array (returned by the magic `find_*` method), and not an ActiveRecord object.

That said, both methods are the *worst* way to do this, if you're simply interested in the number of matching records.

Instead of instantiating the entire result set just to find its length, use `.count` on an actual ActiveRecord relation:

```
@num_users = User.where(country: params[:country]).count
@num_posts = Post.where(category: params[:category]).count
```

This will actually execute as `select count(*) from` instead of a full `select * from`, which will be much faster depending on the number of results.

Comment: Thanks how would you make it faster if not using counter_cache

Comment: @Foo What makes you think you can make it any faster? `.length` and `.count` are so fast that you probably can't measure them. If you want to just find the number of matching records, see my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was just imagining that more than 10000 people load the page at the same time. Then there will be many Posts that has comments for each. Obviously it has the number of the comments each post has. I want to show those number with count. Not counter cache for some reason.  If there are 50 posts shown in the page. 10000 people x 50 posts count will  be running. So I wanted to make it faster as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. What if you are trying to fetch @users with the same condition? can you mix them together? or you just have to have 2 lines like `@users = User.find_all_by_country(params[:country])`   and `@num_users = User.where(country: params[:country]).count` ?

Comment: @Ashitaka Sorry, but no, you're wrong and you've missed some pretty important details that I took explicit pains to outline in my answer. He isn't using `.length` or `.count` on an ActiveResource object. He's invoking it on a dumb array, where `length` and `count` are identical.

Comment: Your previous answer wasn't that clear. You mentioned AREL and didn't differentiate between dumb arrays and activerecord objects (which I clearly missed, my bad). However, it's obvious that Foo should be using a `find_all_by` method when all he wants to do is a count query.

Comment: My "previous answer" was posted **40 minutes** before your comment. Nice try. My answer as it reads now is exactly how it read when you left your comment. Both versions of my answer stated explicitly that he shouldn't be using `find_all_by` and should use `where`, which you've now copied into your answer.

Comment: @meagar why would you not think ahead? Then you have to waste time fixing old code because you were to lazy to find the best way to code something. That is bad practice.