# Rails includes and eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails command:

```
Product.includes(:sale, :product_description).select('distinct on (size) *')
```

It is my understanding that when I run this command, Rails will eagerly load the results into memory, and since there are only 4 sizes, the result should only contain 4 records. However, if I do something like:

```
result = Product.includes(:sale, :product_description).select('distinct on (size) *')
```

and then do: `result.size`. The result will be a count of all the product records, which is 435. But if I do: `result.length` then I will get the expected response, which is 4.

Why am I getting different results with `length` and `size`? I thought that by using `includes` everything is eagerly loaded so `length` and `size` should return the same count?

Also note, if I run `length` first and then `size`, both return the correct result of 4. But if I run `size` first, then I get the wrong response of 435.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are subtile differences between `count`, `size` and `length` on `ActiveRecord::Relations` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794742/2483313) about the details)

In your example `length` will always perform the exact query as defined on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` and will then call `length` on the returned array.

Whereas `result.size` will perform a `count` query when the `ActiveRecord::Relation` wasn't loaded before. Because `count` returns a number (and not actual records) the query is optimized and the `include` and the `select` parts are ignored. This makes sense from a performance point of view.

But if the `Relation` is already loaded (for example when you call `length` before `size`) then `size` will just return the size of the already loaded array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That make sense, but I thought if I used includes then the Relation should load the array since it uses eager loading, meaning that size should not ignore the include or select? Why would size ignore the includes and select parts?

Comment: No, because `includes` doesn't guarantee to run a SQL `JOIN` and to result in only one single query. `includes` might cause in two queries - one for the records and a second loading all associated records at once (What is still faster than N+1 queries - the problem `includes` aiming to solve.

Comment: And `select` is ignored because `count` uses its own `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!